# JavaScript query does not work correctly within a function, no results are shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

UPDATE.

I've now added a screen shot of the parse data browser showing a row using customer number 21.

[image]

UPDATE.

Based on the comments below and the suggested answer I have updated my code. It functions without error but does not appear to have the desired result.

I see two issues.

Once, I don't see anything being stored in the cname or cnumber variables, they appear undefined.

Secondly, I wanted the result of the user typing in a number (searchnumber) into the input box that matches that stored (cnumber) in parse to then return this parse object to the user.

---

Whats wrong with this code? it runs in the browser without errors in Chrome dev tools, but does not appear to return the "CustomerObject" If I run it outside of the function and without the search button it will work, be it only return an empty object.

Is there a problem with my code structure?

```
HTML

  <input type="text" name="searchnumber" id="searchnumber" value="" placeholder="Customer Number"/>  
  <button type="submit" onclick = "search()" >Find</button>
```

JS

```
function search() {
    var CustomerObject = Parse.Object.extend("CustomerObject");
    var retrieve = new Parse.Query(CustomerObject);  
    retrieve.equalTo("customernumber", $('#searchnumber').val()); 
            retrieve.first({ 
                success: function(retrieveResults) 
            {

            }

        });
            var cname = retrieve.get("customername");  
            var cnumber = retrieve.get("customernumber");

      };
```

Comment: Looks like you have not taken into account that this is an _asynchronous_ method …

Comment: in your function never return object, you should have define your object before return for can return like this funcion retrieve(){ var temp={"id":1,"name":"hello"}; return temp;}, i dont know if this action do you want to done

Comment: The query runs, you're just not doing anything with the results.  You need to do all post-processing inside the success handler, accessing retrieveResults and calling other methods from there.

Comment: If someone can provide the code example in the answer I'm happy to accept that and the feedback in the comments.

Comment: Please also show the code where you are using the values of `cname` and `cnumber` as you will need to have all that code inside the `success` function.

Comment: @TimothyWalters all the code is currenly included in the original question. At the moment the issue appears to be querying parse to check if the data exists. Unless you feel like something further should be added to the success function to validate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the success function, do this:

```
var cname = retrieveResults.get("customername");
var cnumber = retrieveResults.get("customernumber");
```

You should rename retrieveResults to `object` or `customerObject` or something.

You're trying to get customername and number from the query, not the retrieved object.

Full code:

```
function search() {
    var CustomerObject = Parse.Object.extend("CustomerObject");
    var retrieve = new Parse.Query(CustomerObject);
    retrieve.equalTo("customernumber", $('#searchnumber').val());
    retrieve.first({
        success: function(customerObject) {
            var cname = customerObject.get("customername");
            var cnumber = customerObject.get("customernumber");
            ...
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks!  To make sure I understand, I thought this code would query parse to look to see if the number entered in the input box (#searchnumber)  matched the number stored against (customernumber) in parse, if a match was found then I could then do something further with the matched object.

Comment: Yes, the equalTo will match customernumber with the value from #searchnumber, and only return an object if match is found.

Comment: Ok, thats what I'm looking to achieve, when i run the code though and enter "21" intot he input box, no object seems to be returned? http://kudosoo.com/findfriends.html

Comment: So, show me a screenshot of your data browser for a row where customernumber is 21

Comment: What if you comment out the equalTo line and use retrieve.find instead? "customerObject" should in this case be an array containing 1 object. Can you check that it does?

Comment: I'll move this to chat. I made the suggested change, but still not working.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52305/discussion-between-dano007-and-handsomeguy)